# OnCollisionEnter2D not called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a script on an elevator that is supposed to teleport the player when they are next to it and press <kbd>e</kbd>

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class interactible : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Transform pos;

    private bool collide;

    void Start()
    {
        collide = false;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collider)
    {
        collide = true;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collider)
    {
        collide = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("e") && collide)
        {
            player.position = pos.position;
        }
    }
}
```

I have defined both player and pos and have made a 2d box collider for the elevator and set "is trigger" to `true`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that 2 triggers can't collide, only triggers and colliders can work with each other.

UPDATE: The main problem turned out to be that when you're dealing with triggers, you need to use `OnTriggerEnter2D` instead of `OnCollisionEnter2D`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Your player has to be a non trigger, triggers cannot trigger other triggers because they look for colliders

Comment: if this is what your saying, my player does not have "is trigger" set to true but the elevator does, so it should work.

Comment: oh I just forgot I have to use a rigidbody don't I?

Comment: @swisscheez84 I'll hop on my computer and we'll work through it in chat

Comment: @SwissCheez84 nevermind, I don't think you can do chat at 1 reputation, pm me your discord

Comment: sorry for the late response whats your discord

Comment: I don't want to post it publicly and it seems this website doesn't have pm options. Also though, @ArtZolinaIII has a point that I didn't realise, your other code might be the issue. Did you try doing any kind of debug output to see if the code that turns your collison flag on and off is being reached?

Comment: yes I have and its just not colliding it knows when I press the 'e' key but collide is always false because its not colliding

Comment: I can give you mine but I will delete it right after we start talking

Answer (score 0):

`Input.GetKeyDown` accept enum so it should be

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && collide)
```

Comment: it isnt that because I took away the "&& collide" and it worked when I press 'e'

Comment: OnCollisionEnter() trigger on a fraction of second so it is difficult to capture keypress at the same time so try to use OnTriggerStay or use LineCast.